# Is there a term for a group 'owning' a previous insult?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a term or word for the process of a group of people taking (or attempting to) an insulting word/phrase and making it their own? I'm thinking about something more than normalization or desensitization but more of a process of almost making it part of their identity.

For example, 'queer' and 'gay' used to be insulting terms for homosexual people. However now it is included in the LGBTQ acronym. On the flip side, 'Faggot' is still insulting and no attempt has been made to 'own' it.

To a lesser extent the word 'nigger' has been taken on and used by various people in songs etc. I believe someone tried to trademark the word 'nigga' as a brand name for genuine business purposes. The attempts to 'own' this insulting word have been less successful than 'queer'.

What is the word or term for this process?

Comment: No need for disclaimers. As this is a language analysis site within SE, anything goes for taboo words in the text of a question or answer as long as it is -about- the word and not using it (well. don't be a **** about it, pragmatically speaking). But please bowdlerize titles as those appear on the front page and in much more public places like the Hot Network Questions that should be SFW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process is known as [**reclaiming** or sometimes **reappropriating**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation).

See uses such as

- https://www.huffpost.com/entry/how-jillian-michaels-is-reclaiming-fag-and-dyke_n_569d1303e4b0ce4964253749
- https://www.facebook.com/1236939913080962/posts/on-behalf-of-all-jews-im-hereby-reclaiming-kike-as-a-word-to-refer-to-a-jewish-b/2313647942076815/
- https://www.huffpost.com/entry/8-women-on-why-they-are-reclaiming-the-word-fat_b_57eec8d0e4b0972364deb2e4

> On the flip side 'Faggot' is still insulting and no attempt has been made to 'own' it.

This is quite incorrect, *many* attempts have been made to reclaim *faggot* and especially *fag*.

Comment: I hadn't or haven't seen many overtly public or successful attempts to reclaim faggot not as much as my examples of gay and queer but I will look through the huff post about Jillian Michaels attempts to do so

Answer (score 0):

[idioms](/questions/tagged/idioms)

I asked a [follow up](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586113/448997) to this question, which broadened the scope to words which are unrelated to group identities (so the follow-up is not a duplicate).  In the comments someone mentioned an expression which happens to answer this question, too.

to [wear (something) as a badge of honor](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wear+it+as+a+badge+of+honor)

To consider something to be a point of pride, *especially that which is typically considered negative.*

Although, obviously it's not a single-word (as requested), it is an idiom which conveys the meaning.