# Is there a word for "insults that you take as a compliment"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example a person insults someone, the victim of the insult understands that they have just been insulted but instead takes it as a badge of honor and turns into a compliment for themselves

Comment: This would be country dependent. As far as I can tell in the US there’s no single word. In the UK I can imagine a simple ‘Right’ in the proper context would communicate the sentiment clearly.

Comment: It’s spelled compliment, though.

Comment: There's the saying ["I'll take that as a compliment"](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-Ill-take-that-as-a-compliment-mean-or-imply-How-is-this-phrase-used-in-conversation) said when someone says something meant as a criticism.

Comment: Do you mean a term for the defused insult, or a term for the addressee's so defusing the insult?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523574/is-there-a-term-for-a-group-owning-a-previous-insult

Comment: *Badge of honor* is perfect—why look further? It's now an award-winning compliment.

Comment: *Notoriety* comes very close. A *cause célèbre* might work in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The recipient of the insult is treating it as an **asteism** by taking the insult as a compliment.

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asteism),

> (1) Polite irony; a genteel and ingenious manner of deriding another.

Whilst the person giving the insult did not intend it to be taken as such, the recipient is interpreting it as a form of [backhanded compliment.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insult#Backhanded_compliments)

Comment: This word is utterly obscure and for all practical purposes unknown.