# Does "reclaiming" only apply to group-identity derogatory words (turned into terms of empowerment)?

Tags: etymology, terminology

I have a follow up to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/523574/448997),

> Is there a term or word for the process of a group of people taking (or attempting to) an insulting word/phrase and making it their own?

which received [the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/523585/448997) that ["reclaiming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reappropriation) can be used to describe the process by which words used to demean group identity turn into self-ascribed terms of empowerment.

**I am curious if "reclaiming" can be used when this is done with words which are not related to any group identity.**

Specifically, can it be said that using "badass," as a complement, is a *result of reclaiming* "badass?"

As another example, can it be said that, *as a result of reclaiming*, "dork" is not only used to mean "socially-inept fool," but also as a self-description of someone who is blissfully ignorant of breaking social norms?  For example, is saying "yeah, I pick my nose because I am a dork.  Deal with it!" a reclaiming of the word "dork?"

If the answer is "no," is there another term for such a pattern of repurposing words?

Comment: If a word is used to insult people, and you feel it applies to you, sure, you can reclaim it. One good example was Obamacare, which Obama reclaimed after it was used by people who wanted to make fun of his wanting to extend healthcare to more people. Another is the word n*****, when rappers et al reclaimed it. There is no repurposing. You are free to reclaim any word you feel applies to you as an insult.

Comment: Didn't Thatcher reclaim *Iron Lady* as a badge of honor?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think you accidentally answered the question.  "Badge of honor" is the more common way to describe this outcome.  Can you add it as an answer to this question or to the one to which I linked?

Comment: You can only reclaim something if you had an original right to it and someone has appropriated it for their own use. In this use, it seems to mean "claim". The nature of the object or concept seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: What @Greybeard said. If the group-identity derogatory term never applied to *your* "group", you obviously can't "REclaim" it. But you can certainly ***commandeer*** it, or use any number of similar terms that don't imply you ever had it before.

Comment: @Greybeard This makes a lot of sense. But I feel like documented use contradicts it. (With the disclaimer that I'm not an expert in the history of any of these terms,) it seems there is a long list of identifiers that started as epithets and became adopted by the group in question—Christian, Methodist, Yankee, queer, the n-word. It seems that almost all of these terms start their life being imposed on the group by those outside it, and although the word "reclaim" is often used for the group's adoption, it doesn't technically meet the "re-" requirement.

Comment: @Greybeard, the word *reclaim* has long had a broader usage than *to take back something once owned*.  When the Dutch drain a marsh, or build a dike and pump out the water, they *reclaim* the land, whether or not it once belonged to them.  *Reclaimed* lumber is not recovered from looters, it's ***re***purposed.  In general, *reclaim* often seems synonymous with *repurpose* or *reappropriate*.

Comment: @AndyBonner that's what make it a term.  If a word's meaning could be understood in its plain meaning, it wouldn't be a term.  It would be just a word.

Comment: Not sure badass is negative enough to be reclaimed. It's always been used as a compliment whether in the 70s or today. Otherwise, fine.

Comment: @StuartF in the [1st sense](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/badass) as in "unruly" or "antisocial," which has transitioned into "nonconformist."  While the 2nd meaning, as in a "tough guy," could have been a positive connotation, the 1st meaning was reclaimed because nonconformism came to be seen as an asset rather than as a liability.

Comment: @Juhasz I see where you're coming from but if you reclaim land, someone or something (the sea) had claimed it before – you are making a second claim on it. If you reclaim lumber, you take ownership of “wood” whose owner has relinquished their claim  – you are making a second claim on it. This transference of the verb in reference to “terms” is heroic rhetoric as all words are available to everyone and nobody may lay claim to any of them† . Heroic rhetoric often goes against what is correct. -- †trade names excepted.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think the second case applies since the words are not the same. The socially acceptable term in the 19th century was **-gro (from Spanish "negro", meaning "black"). The derogatory term used in the 19th to 21st century is **-gger, likely a declension that comes from occupational declension (e.g. singer, digger, dancer, lawyer). The non-derogatory term used in the black community is **-gga, which obviously comes from the prior term but using the prior term is extremely offensive, even if a black person were to use it, whereas the latter is not and is commonly used like "guy" is.

Comment: @uberhaxed Nope. The -gger and -gga are both reclaimed by some Black Americans such as rappers. And in fact so is negro. I recently saw a series where the lady called her husband that whenever she was angry or annoyed at him.

Comment: @Lambie I can say with certainty that unless you are a celebrity and purposefully create attention, such as your examples with rappers, any black person will be extremely offended by -gger. Let's not take our acceptance lessons from Hollywood.

Comment: @uberhaxed It is not just Hollywood. It's in the lyrics. Geesus. And white people are not supposed to use it. https://www.lyrics.com/lyrics/nigger Go tell those rappers not to use it and please do not lecture me about it.

Comment: @Lambie Rappers, as I mentioned, are celebrities. You cannot extrapolate the population from celebrities because they intentionally do controversial things to get attention (because that's their job).

Comment: @uberhaxed Wrong. Rappers use words commonly used in their communities: the vernacular. That's the whole point of rapping. I can't believe I even have to write this.

Comment: 'Reclaiming' has to do with restoring a former sense, not just repurposing.